# sort rich:column by two properties

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces

I try to sort a table by two different properties but I have just one column. How would you do it? I tried with ternary operator but it did not work.

```
<rich:column sortBy="#{someController.sortByName ? item.name : item.id}">
```

Here is the button that toggles sorting type.

```
<a4j:commandLink id="sort-button" action="#{someController.toggleSorting()}" render="my-datatable sort-button">
        <span class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Sortieren nach #{someController.activeSortField == "Bid" ? "Name" : "Bid" }</span>
</a4j:commandLink>
```

As a workaround I added an empty column just for sorting purposes.

```
 <rich:column sortBy="#{scs.name}" sortOrder="#{someController.nameOrder}"/>
 <rich:column sortBy="#{scs.bid}" sortOrder="#{someController.bidOrder}" ...
```

Comment: That should work, show more of your code (e.g. how are you switching between the two?)

Comment: Thank you for your attention. There is a a4j commandLink that I use to toggle active sorting (simple string property) and then rerender the datatable.

Comment: What scope is your bean?